# Unable to mock get_redis function with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I am using fakeredis and pytest on an application

My get_redis function on file `app/helpers/providers.py`:

```
from redis import ConnectionPool, Redis

redis_pool = None


def get_redis() -> Redis:
    global redis_pool
    if redis_pool is None:
        redis_pool = ConnectionPool()
    return Redis.from_pool(redis_pool)
```

Then I use it on my code, located at `app/endpoints/secrets.py`:

```
from app.helpers.providers import get_redis

@router.get("/secrets/{secret_id}")
async def get_secret(
    request: Request,
    secret_id: UUID,
    credentials: Annotated[HTTPBasicCredentials, Depends(security)],
    redis: Redis = Depends(get_redis),
):
    with redis.pipeline() as pipe: # I use redis from get_redis here
        pipe.get(key)
        pipe.delete(key)
        results = pipe.execute()

    return results # just to simplify
```

Then on my tests I have the following:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import patch

import fakeredis
import pytest
from fastapi import HTTPException, status
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient


@pytest.fixture
def fake_redis():
    return fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis()


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_redis_dependencies(fake_redis):
    with patch('app.endpoints.secrets.get_redis', return_value=fake_redis):
        yield


sys.path.append(".")

from app.endpoints.secrets import router


def test_secret_not_found(fake_redis):
    client = TestClient(router)
    with pytest.raises(HTTPException) as exc:
        client.get(
            "/api/secrets/aaaaaaaa-bbbb-4ccc-aaaa-eeeeeeeeeef1",
            auth=("admin", "admin"),
        )

    assert exc.value.status_code == status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
```

The test fails because it tries to use the real redis, which raises an exception.

What I am doing wrong? I have another test that works fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with FastAPI's dependency injection system but I'd say it's the culprit here. `Depends` takes the real `get_redis` function before the patching occurs. My guess is that if (just for the sake of testing) you redefined the `redis` argument by adding `redis = get_redis()` at the beginning of the `get_secret` function, your test would work and the expected mock Redis instance would be used. Obviously, that't not what you want to do but if you identify that `Depends` is the problem, it might steer you in the direction towards the real solution.

Comment: I removed that and changed to `get_redis().pipeline`, same problem.

Comment: You could try to use `mock_redis_dependencies` fixture instead of `fake_redis`, so when you run your test_secret_not_found, a proper fixture is called.

Comment: Still not mocking

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_redis_dependencies(monkeypatch, fake_redis):
    monkeypatch.setattr("app.decorators.rate_limit.redis", fake_redis)
    monkeypatch.setattr("app.endpoints.secrets.redis", fake_redis)
```